# Change Xaml grid.row and column value from c#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am looking for a way to change my Grid.column and my Grid.Row Xaml value from  C# but I cannot see how

Here is my Xaml code :

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" >

                        <Label   FontSize="27" Text="⦿" TextColor="White"  x:Name="otherbookslabel"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnOtherNews"  />
                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Label>

                        <Grid RowSpacing="5" ColumnSpacing="5"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="MainGridNews"  >

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" x:Name="GridRectangle"  ></StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  BackgroundColor="Beige" x:Name="GridCarreGaucheMilieu" ></StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"  BackgroundColor="Accent"   x:Name="GridCarreDroiteBas"  ></StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="OldLace"   x:Name="GridCarreGaucheBas"  ></StackLayout>

                        </Grid>

                    </StackLayout>
```

I started the functiion in c#:

```
   public void OnOtherNews(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove it and then re-add it at the new position

```
myGrid.Children.Remove(myElement);
myGrid.Children.Add(myElement, col, row);
```